# Visual Studio 2015 RTM FREEZE on Universal App Creation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, freeze

Yesterday I installed the Windows 10 SDK for Visual Studio 2015 RTM , there is no way to create a universal app because the IDE will freeze. Am I alone in this?

Comment: Having the same problem, not only after app creation, but also when opening a universal app project

Comment: Seeing the same thing, might be partial related to Nuget 3.0 reliance.

Comment: I dont know man , today it crashed and glitched my desktop UI , it is so buggy on Windows 10 , I think VS 2015 it's ok , it's Windows 10 that is buggy , no idea.

Comment: I have the same problem. Everything was working fine until an overnight Windows update was installed automagically. Now, all Universal Apps freeze on startup. I tried all sorts of uninstalls / reinstalls with no success. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well to be honest after a while I had problems but now it works , but VS 2015 is so buggy , sometimes does not want to build Store packages , Debugger crashes , anyway I am sure they will sort things out.

Comment: do you save your project on onedrive or other cloud?
try to move it to your desktop before create app packages @MihailGeorgescu

Comment: I experienced this issue on the release date of Windows 10 , no idea but VS 2015 didn't work at all  , and no the project was saved locally. Later the issue fixed by itself , no idea what happened. Even rebooted and all. Meh , all good now.